# Creating case-sensitive or 'camelCase' XML nodes using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, excel

I need to create some case-sensitive XML nodes in JavaScript which have attribute names with a colon in between them.

Example: `<Data ss:Type="String">Contact Name</Data>`

When I try to create an element via JavaScript with the `createElement()` function it creates it in lowercase. Also, there are a lot of problems adding the attributes with a colon in them. For example: `ss:Type="String"`

This is **Excel** data, and I am saving the the source **.xml** file back to an **.xls** file. The case of the XML elements and attributes is very important for Excel to be able to read the file.

Any examples or pointers will be great help.

Comment: A couple of tips: 1) XML is case sensitive, that isn't an option 2) Those semicolons are called "namespaces"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13683355/1497596) by Paul S. lead me to a solution.

I created the required XML DOM elements with `createElement()` and added the required attributes with `setAttribute()`. This resulted in:

```xml
<data ss:type="String">Contact Name</data>
```

Note that the element and attribute name in this example are both **lower-case**. However, what I *really* wanted was [Pascal case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase):

```xml
<Data ss:Type="String">Contact Name</Data>
```

After first converting the XML DOM to a string via `XMLSerializer()` as suggested by Paul S., I then simply used `replace()` to convert all occurrences of `<data` to `<Data` and `ss:type` to `ss:Type`.

**The solution to my question are XMLSerializer() and String replace() function**

Answer (score 7):

The JavaScript methods you are looking for are [`document.createElementNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) and [`elm.setAttributeNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttributeNS)

```
var e = document.createElementNS('http://www.microsoft.com/office/excel/', 'Data');
e.setAttributeNS('http://www.microsoft.com/office/excel/', 'ss:Type', 'String');
e.textContent = 'Contact Name';
```

Then if you want to get strings back, `.innerHTML` won't work anymore so you have to use an [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer)

```
var s = new XMLSerializer();
s.serializeToString(e);
```

Comment: The _ss:_ prefix on _Type_ is still disappearing. Still looking.

Comment: Seems to be browser specific? (chrome ignores it, firefox adds lots of xmlns attribs). Parsing string yourself after printing seems like the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for putting effort into this. I got an answer and posting it below. +1 as your answer is certainly helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's a dated question but i'll give my answer:
When using `window.document` to create elements you are using an [`HTMLDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument) (with ns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml") and nodes created with it responds to html standards with the limitations you experienced.
You should use a [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) instead to handle generic XML.

```
// instantiate a new Document  
var xml_doc = document.implementation.createDocument('optional_namespace','rootElement');  

//  then your code to create element  
var e = xml_doc.createElementNS('http://www.microsoft.com/office/excel/', 'Data');  
e.setAttributeNS('http://www.microsoft.com/office/excel/', 'ss:Type', 'String');  
e.textContent = 'Contact Name';  

// probably append it  
xml_doc.documentElement.appendChild(e);  

// serialized xml_doc:  
var s = new XMLSerializer();  
s.serializeToString(xml_doc);  

/*
<rootElement xmlns="optional_namespace">
  <Data xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/office/excel/" xmlns:ss="http://www.microsoft.com/office/excel/" ss:Type="String">Contact Name</Data>
</rootElement>"
*/
```

*EDIT*: tested in Chrome and FF